# rendering fb-like buttons with knockoutjs

Tags: facebook, knockout.js, xfbml

My page contains list of posts, each post has its own like button. The posts are JSON-ly retrieved from the server. Each like should have ofcourse its own href, which is part of the post json object. So naturally I'd expect this to work (assuming "fb_data"
is json object {fb_data: {href: my_post_path}):

```
(html fb-like widget code, with simple knockoutjs data-bind)
<li class="fb">
    <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="85" ata-show-faces="false" data-bind="attr: {href: fb_data.href}"></div>
     <span class="like-container"><span class="likebox" title=""></span>&nbsp;Friends<br/>Like this!</span>
</li>
```

so that didn't work.
I tried another approach and implemented custom binding for that purpose:

```
(html)
<li class="fb">
    <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="85" data-show-faces="false" data-bind="render_like: fb_data"></div>
    <span class="like-container"><span class="likebox" title=""></ span>&nbsp;Friends<br/>Like this!</span>
</li>

(js)
ko.bindingHandlers.render_like = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var fb  = valueAccessor();
        $(element).attr(fb);
        FB.XFBML.parse(element);
    }
};
```

ok, that didn't work either. I turn to the hard, ugly, not elegant way and had this:

```
(html)
 <li class="fb" data-bind="render_like: fb_data"></li>

(js)
ko.bindingHandlers.render_like = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var fb   = valueAccessor();
        var fb_like_str = '<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data layout="button_count" data-width="85" data-show-faces="false"' href="' + fb.href  + '" </div>';
        fb_like_str +=  '<span class="like-container"><span class="likebox" title=""></span>&nbsp;Friends<br/>Like this!</span>';
        $(element).html(fb_like_str);
        FB.XFBML.parse(element);
   }
};
```

that one worked, but it doesn't feel like the knockout spirit ... what
is the problem with the first 2??

Comment: The first one should work fine. What error does it give you? You might want to show your javascript code as well.

Comment: It gives no error, it just doesn't bind the href property properly (so the fb-like button doesn't point to the real post)

Comment: Can you post javascript code? Or even better reproduce the issue on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've just figured out what the problem was. Initiating my viewModel should come **after** FB.init, like that -

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 172535899504455, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    var myVM = new myViewModel(rec_data, $("#myselector").get(0));
}
```

now the nice easy first way is working!

Comment: That didn't work for me, I had to go with your binding handlers solution.